# StringBuilder- Write down Header in csv file

Tags: java, string, csv, bufferedwriter

I am using BufferedWriter to write the data in my csv file.

I am trying to generate my header of csv file. However I am able to see only the Testing Date;Seconds; part in the header.I want to see all device name. Could someone check my code especially the printDeviceNames method.
I do not understand the problem.

```
String FILE_HEADER = "Testing Date;Seconds;" + printDeviceNames(DeviceGroups.choosenDevice);

  bufferedWriter.write(FILE_HEADER);

  bufferedWriter.close();// Always close files.

 private static String printDeviceNames(List<String> choosenDevice) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String deviceName : choosenDevice) {
      stringBuilder.append(deviceName);
      stringBuilder.append(";");
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
```

Comment: For now I suspect you didn't close your writer. Can't tell more without seeing proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Then please put that information in your question/example so we wouldn't need to consider it while trying to find possible cause of your problem. In other words always try to provide proper SSCCE.

Comment: Done! Yes you are right I tried to minimize my code and I forgot  the copied this      bufferedWriter.close();// Always close files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like `DeviceGroups.choosenDevice` has empty list, use following code to check what problem

```
System.out.println("DeviceGroups.choosenDevice " + DeviceGroups.choosenDevice);
String FILE_HEADER = "Testing Date;Seconds;" + printDeviceNames(DeviceGroups.choosenDevice);
System.out.println("FILE_HEADER " + FILE_HEADER);

  bufferedWriter.write(FILE_HEADER);

 private static String printDeviceNames(List<String> choosenDevice) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String deviceName : choosenDevice) {
      stringBuilder.append(deviceName);
      stringBuilder.append(";");
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
```

What `System.out.println` shows you? It's look like is shows DeviceGroups.choosenDevice == empty list

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not close the BufferedWriter, then the last buffer still is not written.

This can happen too, when closing the file separately before closing the BufferedWriter. Then simply just close only the BufferedWriter. It closes its underlying file.

Comment: May be, but why `bufferedWriter.write(FILE_HEADER);` write just `Testing Date;Seconds;`? If problem with closing file, it should probably write something like "Testing Date;Seconds;OtherDevi..." or "Testing Date;Secon..." not exactly "Testing Date;Seconds;"